# Help with Formula fields referencing fields updated by trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, field-update

I have a context for QuoteLineItems pricing that uses the list price from the current Pricebook and applies a series of factors (defined in custom fields of both Quote and QuoteLineItems) to compose different pricing stages of the item. I have this scenario implemented via WFR + Field Updates, but trying to migrate this to triggers, since I need more control of execution order for later improvements. This is the scenario I'm trying with triggers:

1. QuoteLineItem has a Formula field `Effective_Unit_Price__c`, which is a really long formula field;
2. QuoteLineItem has a Number Field `Effective_Unit_Price_2__c` which is updated via `before update` trigger with contents from `Effective_Unit_Price__c`, so we can use this new one on other formulas ahead in this pricing stages I mentioned. I need this because the previous field was already too long; *(this update was being done by field update)*
3. QuoteLineItem has a Formula field `Total_Price__c` which is a formula field referencing that `Effective_Unit_Price_2__c` plus some Quote's field (cross-object reference).
4. QuoteLineItem has another Number field called `Total_Price_2__c` which is updated via `before update` trigger:

> ```
> ...
> item.put('Total_Price_2__c', item.get('Total_Price__c'));
> ...
> ```

5. Quote has a roll-up summary field which sums up this `Total_Price_2__c` (that is the reason I make that copy, because there is a restriction of roll-up for cross-object formula fields);

So, basically I want this propagation of values:

```
QLI.Effective_Unit_Price__c -> Qli.Effective_Unit_Price_2__c -> QLI.Total_Price__c -> QLI.Total_Price_2__c
```

The order of those `before update` triggers in QuoteLineItem (it is a single trigger, using methods from a handler class):

```
  trigger QuoteLineItemTrigger on QuoteLineItem (before insert, before update, after delete) {

  if (trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate) {
      Map<Id, PricebookEntry> entries = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>([... QUERY ...]);
      List<QuoteLineItem> new_items = trigger.new;

      // Updating some long-formula fields of QuoteLineItems
      QuoteLineItemTriggerHandler.UpdateWkFields(new_items, entries);

      // Copies calculated values from formula fields with cross-object formula to new fields, to be used in roll-up summary fields
      QuoteLineItemTriggerHandler.CopyCrossObjectFormulaFields(new_items);
  }
```

However, my desired output is not being achieved. Here is an example:

1. Before running triggers, `Effective_Unit_Price__c` is 1000 and all other fields are 0;
2. First trigger runs (Effective Unit Price fields), populates `Effective_Unit_Price_2__c` with 1000; Both `Total_Price__c` and `Total_Price_2__c` are still 0;
3. Second trigger runs (Total_Price fields) but since the source value is still 0, target field remains as 0;

What I am doing wrong? Is there some other better solution to get this desired propagation of values? Or shouldn't I be moving to triggers? Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: Are there 2 before update triggers for the same object ? If so as per docs(additional considerations) : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htmThe order of execution isn’t guaranteed when having multiple triggers for the same object due to the same event. For example, if you have two before insert triggers for Case, and a new Case record is inserted that fires the two triggers, the order in which these triggers fire isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: It is one single trigger, calling a trigger handler class methods in that order, I added some extra code in the original post to make that clearer.

Comment: Are you querying the formula field Effective_Unit_Price__c in your before update trigger? the formula field value may not be accessible in your before trigger context.

Comment: I'm not making any query in any step, I'm just using trigger.new objects.

Comment: Im asking you to modify your logic to include the Effective_Unit_Price__c 
 from QuoteLineItems [Select Effective_Unit_Price__c from QuoteLineItems  where Id IN:Trigger.new ] and see what comes out

Comment: In which point exactly? That field is the only one that is OK, propagating its value is not working. I set the Effective_Unit_Price_2__c in the trigger and wanted to use a formula field that references it to populate Total_Price_2__c, but it is not set yet. If I make that query you suggested, it will return the original values of the items, as the trigger has not finished yet and objects were not saved with populated values.